# Can't Convert SVG to PDF with PDFKit in Python without Loosing Images

Tags: python, pdf, svg, pdfkit

I am having trouble converting my .SVG files to .PDF's. I am embedding the .SVG code inside html and trying to load the pdf from a string. Everything shows up fine except for the embedded images. They don't show up at all. Here is an example of the svg for an image...

```
<image xlink:href="data:image.png;base64, '...'" height="45", width="70", y="10", x="10" />
```

Where the '...' is filled with a correct base64 string. I have double checked the base64 code personally as well. Any idea of what could be wrong would be greatly appreciated!